# mock for react-intl with using useIntl

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, react-intl

I'm using useIntl hook in my component. In my test I mock useIntl in file react-intl.js in src/**mocks** directory. Also in this file, I mock defineMessages, that are used in many other components.

The part of mock with defineMessages in src/**mocks**/react-intl.js looks like

```
export const defineMessages = jest.fn(() => ({
  defineMessages: jest.fn((...args) => JSON.stringify(args))
}));
```

The mock of useIntl looks the same, it works.

The problem is when I start the tests, I get undefined in places where I use defineMessages. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code that helped me to resolve the problem.

```
export const defineMessages = jest.fn(message => message);
```